# Objective-C get default apps

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to get default apps for: Firewall, Mail, Office, Antivirus.
Something similar to what exists in Windows:
[image: Default Windows Programs]
I suppose there is something similar for OSX and can be retrieved programatically.

I have managed to get the Mail app, but I don't know how to get the others:

```
CFURLRef mailURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("mailto://"), NULL);
CFURLRef mailAppURL = NULL;
OSStatus ret = 0;
if((ret = LSGetApplicationForURL(mailURL, kLSRolesAll, NULL, &mailAppURL)) == 0) {
  CFStringRef path = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(mailAppURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac OS X does not have default programs for activities or tasks, but it has default programs for URL schemes and file extensions.  Like the code you have for mail, you could find a default web browser by finding the default handler for the http URL scheme.  As for media players, you could pick a media type like .mp4 or .mp3 and then get its default handler using `LSGetApplicationForInfo`, but I suppose it is possible that .mp4 and .mp3 have different default handlers.  I don't know any way to find a default antivirus program or firewall.

The title asks for an Objective-C method, and I suppose one could use `-[NSWorkspace URLForApplicationToOpenURL:]` instead of the Launch Services functions.